# Tags bug when asking a question from a previously saved draft wherein no tags are set yet

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, draft

When you type your question, quit the page and open it again later in time, the question you previously entered is still there, as a draft. However, if you haven't entered any tags yet, you get this crazy result:

[image]

There are two problems with this:

1. The tags should still be empty.
2. SO yells at me **three** times I may only enter five tags or less.

Can someone fix this? :)

---

I think this is caused by saving the default text (at least … 5 tags) is saved with the draft. Maybe a good future-<kbd>feature-request</kbd> when IE finally understands HTML 5 (I guess it will be in IE 17 or something) using `<input placeholder="at least … 5 tags" etc... />`.

---

I am using Safari on Mac OS X 10.6.6 Snow Leopard without any malware installed.

Comment: I've experienced the same with Firefox.

Comment: @Hendrik thanks, I'll remove the footnote.

Comment: Hm... I saw this happen for a *split second* here when loading up a draft on Meta, but immediately afterwards all of the tags collapsed and it was not treated as having any tags. So no warnings other than the fact I needed to enter some tags. IE8 on XP here.

Comment: By the way, the same thing happens with the title: I got the nice message "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed." since the title was "what's your question? be specific." (apropos specific: Firefox 3.6.13 on Vista)

Comment: @Hendrik this means it's a bug with the placeholders. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder text and the actual contents (i.e. tags or text) of the text box are now two separate things, so this shouldn't happen anymore (see [Jeff's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77086/textbox-placeholders-dont-behave-as-expected-for-focus-or-drag-and-drop/77088#77088) for why the regular `placeholder="..."` functionality is a non-starter.)

Well, technically, if your browser remembers the "at least one such tag..." text from before this fix, it could still happen for a moment (because that text is in the text field, meaning it's denoting tags); but there shouldn't be any more new instances of this problem popping up.