# Textbox placeholders don't behave as expected for focus or drag and drop

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

A lot of textboxes have the entire "label-as-placeholder" thing going on. This is helpful, but because it's implemented in Javascript, there are a few issues.

For instance, when you click in there, the cursor can just kind of sit in the middle of the placeholder text so it looks like you might just type in the middle of it…

Or, when you're marking a question as a duplicate and the duplicate is in the sidebar, if you drag the link into the text box as if you were going to drop the URL, it just spits it into the middle of the placeholder text. Then, typing won't remove the placeholder text and that's just really annoying.

[image: The text box gets all wonky when you drag stuff into it, and that makes me sad :(. I bet nobody will ever read this text. DOGS ARE BETTER THAN KITTIES, though both are very cute indeed.]

I would suggest using `placeholder=` for this, and using javascript to imitate it if the browser doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder text and the actual textbox content are now seperate things, so the cursor can't be in the help text anymore. Drag-and-drop is still somewhat unsupported in that it looks a little weird until you press a key, but at least the texts won't mix anymore, so the dragged-and-dropped link actually works.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/poiOD.gif

Answer (score 1):

This would be a pyrrhic victory, though, because we set focus to that box as soon as the dialog spawns.

This means the helper text would *NEVER* be visible as all the typical ways (eg the HTML5 one) clear on focus -- and that box always has the focus.

So, unimplementable as suggested.

(I would also add that I consider drag and drop of URLs to be a pretty rare use case for the average internet user, and even the average programmer.)